# how does the Awesomium JSObject work i can't find an example

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, awesomium

I'm using Awesomium WebControl on a Form in C# and i'm trying to pass information into the browser that a USB device has been plugged in i have the USB detection working but for some reason i can't build a `JSObject()` with the values per device plugged in into it.

Here is the code that is fired when a Device is plugged into the computer

```
JSObject js_obj;

DriveInfo[] allDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();

JSValue[] js_arr = new JSValue[allDrives.Count()];

int count = 0;

foreach (DriveInfo drive in allDrives)
{
    if (drive.IsReady == true)
    {
        if (drive.DriveType == DriveType.Removable)
        {
            js_obj = new JSObject();
            js_obj["Id"] = new JSValue("");
            js_obj["TimeAdded"] = new JSValue("");
            js_obj["DriveLetters"] = new JSValue(drive.VolumeLabel);
            js_obj["Port"] = new JSValue("");
            js_arr[count] = new JSValue(js_obj);
            count++;
        }
    }
}

this.Browser.CallJavascriptFunction("DiskDetector", "DeviceAdded", js_arr);
```

But when i add a break point at `this.Browser.CallJavascriptFunction("DiskDetector", "DeviceAdded", js_arr);` js_arr is an array of 4 with where all the values are null

I think the problem is my use of the JSObject and Setting values JSObject Extends IDisposable and i though i would have to all Add("key", "Value"); but the method is not there for me to use

Comment: Put a breakpoint on `js_arr[count] = new JSValue(js_obj);` to see if it ever gets called.

Comment: thanks how the hell did i miss that one i have been working on this for about 5 hours today and a good 8 yesterday and did not even think that it was not entering the loop so windows is doing some thing wrong in the WMI then

Comment: @M.Babcock Please fill out and answer stating that the problem is with WMI a USB Device does not always come though a a Removable Device it can come though as Fixed and i will up it how ever the object is still not working in JS it's creating it but the keys are not set in JS

Comment: Updated answer after testing (roughly) the code from your question. It  certainly works, so I'm not sure what else anyone can do for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

USB drives can sometimes have a `DriveType` of `DriveType.Fixed` rather than `DriveType.Removable`.

---

Just to make sure I didn't miss anything, I've also taken your code (minus your `Removable` condition and referencing `drive.Name` instead of `drive.VolumeLabel` to get the actual drive letter) to see if I could get it to work:

```
JSObject js_obj;

DriveInfo[] allDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();

JSValue[] js_arr = new JSValue[allDrives.Count()];

int count = 0;

foreach (DriveInfo drive in allDrives)
{
    if (drive.IsReady == true)
    {
        js_obj = new JSObject();
        js_obj["Id"] = new JSValue("");
        js_obj["TimeAdded"] = new JSValue("");
        js_obj["DriveLetters"] = new JSValue(drive.Name);
        js_obj["Port"] = new JSValue("");
        js_arr[count] = new JSValue(js_obj);
        count++;
    }
}

foreach (var js_val in js_arr)
{
    if (js_val == null)
        continue;

    Trace.WriteLine(js_val.GetObject()["DriveLetters"].ToString());
}
```

And it outputs:

```
C:\
S:\
T:\
Y:\
Z:\
```

As I expect. I'm still not sure why it isn't working for you, but this proves your usage of `JSObject` is correct.